# Iterate over an array and store values as key and value of an object using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an array of objects of length 535. I want to loop through that array and extract the values inside those objects and store it in a single object while also setting key and value of that single object.

My array looks like:
[image]

Lets call this array: responseData
and every object in the responseData looks like:

```
{
  "Tag": "bgnt",
  "Label": "BeginTime",
  "Description": "The time the event began to occur, if the event source reports events indicating the beginning of length transactions.",
  "Type": "3",
  "Taxonomy": "false",
  "Category": "Uncategorized",
  "Tokenized": "false"
}
```

What I want to do is loop through all objects, and store all objects into a single object say mainObject. And also define key and values of mainObject as
mainObject.key = responseData[i].tag;
mainObject.value = responseData[i].Label;

How do I : 1. Create a mainObject?
           2. Assign key and value of mainObject ?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first iteration: mainObject.key = responseData[0].tag. mainObject.key is now, let's say "hola". then second iteration mainObject.key = responseData[1].tag. now mainObject.key is "chau". so, after walking thru all of them, mainObject will have the same value as your last object in the arrya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need angular for this. Use bracket notation to set the key using the item tag

```
var myObject = {};
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
  myObject[item["Tag"]] = item["Label"];
});

console.log(myObject["bgnt"]); // "Begin Time"
```

Comment: Wow! It worked perfectly. I just can't believe that there was such a straightforward solution.Thank you :)